# Financial Force Report Builder

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Could someone please assist in this error I am receiving in financial force report builder: "Your selected lens is not supported by Financial Report Builder. Review your lens or query method and consult the Help before trying again"

We need to upload the data in CSV format in Analytics Studio first and create Lenses in Analytics studio to be used in creating the financial report in the report builder. For eg: if you want to show the revenue information in the income statement, you create a Lense called revenue and you group by Sum of the revenue and group by the products.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your lens  is created using compact 1.0. Salesforce introduced a new compact lens in their Spring 2023 release. Summer '23 versions of Certinia products will support this version.
Check out the Certinia Community using this error message as the search criteria.